# Password Mode of TextBox in F#

Tags: winforms, f#

I am developing an windows application in F#. In the application I have to show the TextBox mode in `Password Format`. What is the code for using the password mode of TextBox in F#?

I have applied the following code:

```
let txtpwd = new TextBox(Top = 70, Left = 120)
```

From the above code the textbox is displaying. No problem. I have applied following code for password mode:

```
txtpwd.PasswordChar
```

The above code is not working properly.

Comment: Could you show what code you have attempted - even if it is not F#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set [desired properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.TextBox_properties.aspx) upon initialization of your control, for example:

```
txtpwd.Text <- ""         // Set to no text
txtpwd.PasswordChar <-'*' // The password character is an asterisk
txtpwd.MaxLength <- 14    // The control will allow no more than 14 characters
```

Comment: Thanks. Awesome reply. But one more question. How do i apply textbox mode to MultiLine mode?

Comment: I got code for MultiLine. I just have to set the property to true. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Better yet, set the properties in your call to the constructor.  One of the cool things about F# is that you can set properties in the call that you wouldn't normally be able to set in the constructor.  Like this:

```
let txtpwd = new TextBox(Top = 70, Left = 120, Text = "", PasswordChar = '*',MaxLength = 14, Multiline = true)
```

This is basically equivalent to what Gene posted but, as far as I know, it's a little more idiomatic in F#.

If you check this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233192.aspx) under the topic "Assigning Values To Properties At Initialization" (sorry can't post a direct link) although the page is discussing F# code, it holds for other .Net code as well.